eigenvector pairing
In the page 301 of the Linear Algebra and Optimization for Machine Learning book, there is a corollary (7.2.1) about eigenvector pairing. The corollary reads:
Let $B$ be an $m × m$ matrix. Then matrices $B^T B$ and $BB^T$ will have the same set of $m$ eigenvalues $λ_1, ..., λ_m$. Let the $m$ orthonormal eigenvectors of the symmetric matrix $B^TB$ be denoted by $p_1, ..., p_m$ with eigenvalues $λ_1, ...,λ_m$. Then it is possible to find $m$ orthonormal eigenvectors $q_1, ..., q_m$ of $BB^T$ such that the following holds: $λ_i^{1/2}q_i= Bp_i$.
But its proof is not clear. How can one prove that?

Hello! For the sake of assisting others who will be looking to help, are you asking for assistance in understanding the proof provided in your course text? Or are you just asking for any proof of the claim? If the former, you will need to include the proof as detailed in the text, and explain where exactly you're getting stuck. If the latter, it is recommended you provide efforts/attempts (otherwise people will downvote you and shutdown your post, unfortunately).

Not knowing the original proof from your book, I can simply give you an elementary proof of the statement, hoping it can help.
Without loss of generality, we can suppose that $\lambda_i\ne 0$ for $i\leqslant p$ for some $p\leqslant m$. For $i\leqslant p$, set
$$q_i:=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda_i}}Bp_i$$
For $i,j\leqslant p$, if $i\ne j$ then
$$\langle q_i,q_j \rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda_i\lambda_j}}(Bp_i)^\intercal Bp_j=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda_i\lambda_j}}p_i^\intercal B^\intercal Bp_j=\frac{\lambda_j}{\sqrt{\lambda_i\lambda_j}}p_i^\intercal p_j=0 $$
(because $\{p_i\}_i$ is orthonormal), and by the same argument
$$\langle p_i,p_i \rangle=\frac{1}{\lambda_i}p_i^\intercal B^\intercal B p_i=p_i^\intercal p_i=1$$
Hence, $\{q_i\}_{i\leqslant p}$ is an orthonormal family, that can be completed into an orthonormal base $\{q_i\}_{i\leqslant m}$, the missing vectors forming a base for the kernel of $BB^\intercal$. Now, for $i\leqslant p$,
$$BB^\intercal q_i=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda_i}}BB^\intercal Bp_i = \frac{\lambda_i}{\sqrt{\lambda_i}}B p_i= \sqrt{\lambda_i}q_i$$
and by definition
$$\sqrt{\lambda_i}q_i =Bp_i$$
